# Как наложить png изображения друг на друга в java?

Tags: java, spring, изображения, jvm, awt

Пишу клиент-серверное приложение (браузерная игра) в команде. Являюсь backend программистом. Используем java Spring. В одной задаче нам требуется работа с изображениями, а точнее их наложение друг на друга (генератор гербов). Как это можно сделать? Приоритет - производительность и простота. Если под такие параметры во встроенных java классах нет средств, может быть есть сторонние библиотеки, или даже другие языки, совместимые с JVM (Kotlin, JPHP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java есть библиотека [`awt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html) для создания пользовательских интерфейсов и также для рисования графики и изображений. Для наложения одной картинки на другую, можно использовать метод [`drawImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)). Передаём ему на вход картинку [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) и координаты левой верхней точки, куда её рисовать. Для вращения картинки можно использовать метод [`rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate(double,%20double,%20double)).

Например, есть массив картинок `png` с буквами. Нужно составить из них слово, так чтобы каждая последующая буква немного наезжала на предыдущую на 40% её ширины:

```java
int quantity = 10;
int width = 10;
int height = 10;

BufferedImage[] letters = new BufferedImage[quantity];

BufferedImage captchaImg =
        new BufferedImage(width + width * (quantity - 1) / 10 * 6, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    captchaImg.getGraphics().drawImage(letters[i], width * i / 10 * 6, 0, null);
}
```

---

См. [«Creating simple captcha»](https://drakonoved.org/blog/2017/11/07/creating-simple-captcha.html)